# Good Testing approach for a Azure AD B2C

Tags: testing, web-applications, azure-ad-b2c

I am working as a tester on a new Web Application that uses Azure B2C, And I am looking for the appropriate approach to handle this project. Please suggest me some ideas

Answer (score 0):

It's the same approach as testing any Azure AD application.

Test all the profiles e.g. sign up / sign-in / reset password.

For any API secured by B2C, use automated testing and use the Resource Owner Password flow for the credentials.